# Place axis text labels between ticks

Tags: d3.js, label

How can I change where the labels are placed with respect to their ticks?

Currently I have:
[image]

But I obviously don't want the date to be interrupted by the tick. I would like to have this:
[image]

I have tried:

```
.selectAll(".tick text")
.style("text-anchor", "start")
```

and

```
.selectAll("text")
  .attr("x", 5)
  .attr("dy", null)
  .attr("text-anchor", null);
```

and

```
svg.selectAll(".axis2 text")
.attr("dx", -115);
```

None of the above moved the text label in anyway.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: How are you generating those labels? They don't look like what D3 gives you by default.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: This is my 1st axis `var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickSize(-h, 0).tickPadding(6).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));` and 2nd axis `var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top").tickSize(-10, 0).tickPadding(-6).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%B %d, %Y")).ticks(d3.time.day, 1);`

Comment: Ah, you're using two axes. You probably want to do `svg.selectAll(".axis2 > text")` or better `axisContainer.selectAll("text")`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: `svg.selectAll(".axis2 > text")` didn't move the label either. I got `axisContainer` is not defined, do you know what I might be missingt?

Comment: `axisContainer` is the name of the selection variable that you call `xAxis2` on.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I got it working, thanks. I have one more question, I want to use the tick formatting to clearly indicate each day. It looks like this right now http://imgur.com/58b2jXx. I was wondering how I can move the 2nd axis down so that the ticks are underneath the date?

Comment: Just reposition the container.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Sorry, I'm completely new to d3 and just picked up someone else's project. How do I reposition it?

Comment: Presumably you're setting `transform` with a translation on the `g` element that contains the axis. Adjust those translation values as needed.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I'm an idiot! I forgot about `transform`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `text` elements, use `axisContainer.selectAll("text")`, where `axisContainer` is the name of the selection variable that you call `xAxis2` on. Then you can set attributes/styles on them.